# HTML view is not showing inside body tag

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

In codeigniter I have created a view and that view is called inside another view but this view is not showing inside specific div. This view is showing under head tag. I have used code like below examples

```
<div class='test-view'>
    <?php $this->load->view('abc') ?>   
</div>
```

This code was working before but unfortunately linex server was rebuilt. I don't know what is going wrong inside the server or code thats giving me error. Any one can help me why this code is coming outside the div? which extension or module is missing on server. (sorry for bad English).

Thanks

NOTE:- If I am using any html inside PHP code that also not showing in specific div. Like

```
   <div class="for-test">
        <?php $html = '<span>This is only for example. <a href="#">Not a real work</a>.</span>'; 
           $echo $html;
         ?>
   </div>
```

Above code is also not showing inside `<div class="for-test"></div>`

Comment: have you tried `<?php echo $this->load->view('abc') ;?> ` and user guide for views http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html if no data present you need to do `<?php echo $this->load->view('abc', NULL , TRUE) ;?> `

Answer (score 0):

add semicolon end of line

```
 <?php $this->load->view('abc'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing it on this way: send the view to the view as data. Just like this

```
//in the controller
$data['forTestContent'] = $this->load->view('yourView', NULL, TRUE);
$this->load->view ('yourView', $data);



//In the view just use
<div class='test-view'><?= $forTestContent; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter TRUE for the view

```
<div class='test-view'>
<?php $this->load->view('abc', NULL, TRUE) ?>   
</div>
```

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Topic: Return Views as data

Comment: i think thats not a proper way to do that. Thats controllers bussiness

Comment: Yeah. we can use PHP include method to load the view also.  include APPPATH.'views/file.php'

Comment: i dont tell "cant". I tell " shouldnt"